# Combination on point

Tags: combinations

How many tetrahedrons are determined by nine points no four of which lie in the same plane?
When i googled tetrahedrons , it is a 3D triangle . So now , i have no idea how that tetrahedrons will be drawn on the points. Please help me sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when no four points lie on the same plane, any collection of $4$ points from the $9$ available points will give us a tetrahedron, right?

Hence, there are: $\binom94 =126$ ways.

Comment: Ohh i see sir. But why 4 points? Isnt tetrahedron originally a triangle ?

Comment: @Dave A tetrahedron is formed by four points right, a base triangle and an apex...